# Write a custom mongoose plugin to return signed S3 URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, mongoose

I am trying to write a plugin to return regular s3 object as signed URL. The expected outcome is to obtain the S3 object name from `user.profilePhoto` and overwrite it into signed URL in API response. In short, this field store object key name / normal S3 URL but return as signed URL every time the user data is query by find / findAll method.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
   profilePhoto: {
      type: String,
      signurl: true,
    },
)
userSchema.plugin(signURL);
```

Note that I am trying to use signurl option to indicate that the plugin will need to work on this field. It is inspired by [moongose-autopopulate](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate)

How can I access the option to check if the signurl is there? This is what I have tried so far. I have read the moongose-autopopulate source code but struggling to find the hint so far. It should be around [these lines](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate/blob/master/index.js#L30). After spending more time reading the code, I think `getPathsToPopulate` is the key. However, I may need some help on the handler and discriminator explanation.

```
const signURL = (schema, options) => {
  console.log(options) // Undefined
  console.log(this.options) // Undefined
  console.log(this._mongooseOptions) // Undefined
  schema.post(['find', 'findOne'], function (docs) {
      console.log(options) // Undefined
      console.log(this.options) //{}
      console.log(this._mongooseOptions) // Some populate object related to moongose-autopulate
     // I probably need to include the signing logic and override the value to signed URL here
  });
};

module.exports = signURL;
```